# Selecting 5 elements out of an array of n elements and applying Bubble sort on those 5 elements

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

If i am having an array of n elements and I take first 5 elements and apply Bubble sort on them and take 3rd max element out of it. So what will be the time complexity of this.

I am thinking it would be constant.
**Reason** why I think so is

O(1) in selecting 5 elements.
O(5*5)I.e equal to O(1) for Bubble sort and O(1) for 3rd max element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any algorithm that doesn't depend on the input size, is constant. So in your case, it doesn't depend on the array size, so yes, it is constant.